# How to download multiple video playlist by youtube-dl and avoid repeated recheck?

Tags: youtube-dl

I want do download multiple play lists by youtube-dl. Created batch file for links of urls. But when any interrupt occurred after that interrupt youtube-dl restart downloading and check every link again and again and its very time consuming task to check again and already downloaded videos? How to avoid repeated recheck in youtube-dl?
I use following command.

```
youtube-dl -a -c -i batchfileofurls.txt
```

But its time consuming when any interrupt occurred. 
I want to avoid following task when particular videos or links are successfully downloaded.

```
[youtube:playlist] Downloading playlist PLnVcHd3TXd2rH_d1U7LT1BzrsOgUouhfJ - add
 --no-playlist to just download video G0HCqSe__3Q
[youtube:playlist] PLnVcHd3TXd2rH_d1U7LT1BzrsOgUouhfJ: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading playlist: #YodaHacks
[youtube:playlist] playlist #YodaHacks: Downloading 5 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 5
[youtube] G0HCqSe__3Q: Downloading webpage
[youtube] G0HCqSe__3Q: Downloading video info webpage
[download] How To Create A Storyboard Presentation-G0HCqSe__3Q.mp4 has already b
een downloaded
[download] 100% of 17.99MiB
[download] Downloading video 2 of 5
[youtube] Xvx13TrmWLU: Downloading webpage
[youtube] Xvx13TrmWLU: Downloading video info webpage
[download] 7 Killer Chrome Tricks-Xvx13TrmWLU.mp4 has already been downloaded
[download] 100% of 11.16MiB
[download] Downloading video 3 of 5
[youtube] y4L8g9ARz3Q: Downloading webpage
[youtube] y4L8g9ARz3Q: Downloading video info webpage
[download] Read Faster And Smarter-y4L8g9ARz3Q.mp4 has already been downloaded
[download] 100% of 14.32MiB
[download] Downloading video 4 of 5
[youtube] _G9oBDaonOE: Downloading webpage
[youtube] _G9oBDaonOE: Downloading video info webpage
[download] 4 Fun Facts About Google You Never Knew-_G9oBDaonOE.mp4 has already b
een downloaded
[download] 100% of 9.72MiB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running `youtube-dl --help`, I got proper solution.

```
E:\youtube-dl --download-archive archive.txt -c -i -w -a batchfileofurls.txt
```

by using `--download-archive archive.txt` command I save lot of recheck time.